# perl regexp return number of matches, with anchors

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match the number of brackets in a string not commented out

ex:

```
stuff stuff { stuff { // {stuff {
```

should return 2;

this is my attempt so far, but it returns at most 1.

```
$count=()=$line=~/^((?!\/\/).)*?{/g;
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to do this in two steps without a regex:

```
my $string = 'stuff stuff { stuff { // {stuff {';

my ($code) = split '//', $string;
my $count = $code =~ tr/{//;

print $count;
```

Comment: Thanks, That would solve the problem.
Can you please explain what the tr flags do?
Also I interested in an enclosed solution just because, want to learn more regexp.
Maybe this can be done somehow by replacing the matches?

Comment: The transliteration operator, tr, is documented at [`perlop #Quote Like Operators`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators).  And yes, I can sympathize with wanting to learn regex's, but it's equally important to be able to recognzie when not to use them and when to break a problem up.

Answer (score 1):

`^` only matches at the beginning of the string. If you remove it, you get 4:

```
$count = () = "stuff stuff { stuff { // {stuff {" =~ /((?!\/\/).)*?{/g;
print $count, "\n";
```

Comment: I realize that, but I need 2, because the last 2 are "commented out"

Comment: So start with `$line =~ s=//.*==` and process the remaining string.

Comment: Please explain the answer. What does that do?

Comment: I just removed `^` from the start of the regular expression to let it match everywhere. If you don't want to match after `//`, just remove it from the string with anything that follows.